# How to configure HikariCP for Slick 3.0.0 RC1 on Typesafe conf

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.3, hikaricp, slick-3.0

I have a Play Application based on the [play-scala Typesafe template (Play Scala Seed)](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-scala), and tried to add Slick 3.0.0 to the project and connect to a PostgreSQL database.

First I added the dependencies to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0-RC1",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
)
```

Then added the database configuration on `application.conf`:

```
brDb = {
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
  user = "postgres"
  password = "postgres"
  numThreads = 10
}
```

Note that I haven't disabled explicitly the pooling, so it is enabled by default, and will try to use HikariCP, because as of Slick 3.0.0 RC1, [HikariCP support exists and pooling using it is enabled by default](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2015/02/20/slick-3.0.0-RC1-released.html).

And in my DAO object, tried to get the database connection like this:

```
Database.forConfig("brDb")
```

When I run the app using `activator run`, I get this error:

> RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig

Then I tried adding HikariCP as a dependency in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // ...
    "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.3",
    // ...
)
```

Cleaned and recompiled the app using `activator clean compile`, and runned it again, but I get another error:

> RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig

I think I am missing some configuration, but I am not sure and have not found more info about it. How should I set up the configuration to get the connection pool working?

Comment: So I don't get it, why isn't the HikariCP pulled in as a dependency of the new slick version if it obviously depends on it?

Comment: @evermean I am not sure. It seems that the dependency is in the build file for Slick: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.0.0-RC1/project/Build.scala#L36 (I'm new to Scala and Play, so maybe I'm missing something and the dependency is not being pulled by default)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error means that the HikariCP package is compiled for a JRE newer than the one you#re running on. And in fact, if you [look at the homepage](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), you'll see that the version you are using is this:

> Java 8 maven artifact:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
>   <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
>   <version>2.3.5</version>
>   <scope>compile</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

I suppose you're running on Java 7. For that, add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP-java6" % "2.3.3",
)
```

Comment: That was the issue, indeed. Now I have another exception (connection timeout) :( but that will be another question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Btw, I have found out that the configuration structure that you specified above does not actually work as of Slick 3.0.0. What worked for me was to specify the database configuration as described in the documentation http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html#using-typesafe-config, otherwise Slick will assume some default values for the configuration. I'm mainly talking about the "properties" field.

So something like this should work:

```
mydb = {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    serverName = "postgresdb"
    portNumber = "5432"
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "secret"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

Comment: what's the key for setting the timeout on hikaricp? can't find it anywhere

Comment: connectionTimeout at top level (i.e. where you set numThreads).